# Why doesn't lombok provide a getter method for inherited attribute?

Tags: java, lombok

Given that I have the below class

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class A extends B {
}
```

And then class B is as below:

```
@Data
public class B {
    protected Driver driver;
}
```

But, when I try to get the driver by the following code:

```
A a = new A();
a.getDriver();
```

But it complains with:

```
The method getDriver() is undefined for the type A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the `AccessLevel` on the `driver` field:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
protected Driver driver;
```

You can read more about the `AccessLevel` here in the documentation:
https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AccessLevel.html

Comment: what is the library of `AccessLevel`?

Answer (score 8):

Because driver is `protected` and `Data` all generated getters and setters will be public (according to documentation).
It is trying to access higher level privileges. 
Try:

```
 import lombok.AccessLevel;
 @Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) protected Driver driver;
```